# How to approach implementing a new sync mode in Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

Has anyone ever tried implementing your own sync mode in Geth? What's the recommended flow of code change in order to implement your own sync mode?

Comment: The question is interesting but too broad to be precisely answered. I personally would start with analysing how the existing sync code works. If you're not able to understand this first, then it will be very difficult to add your own sync mode.

Comment: The question is what sync mode are you thinking about?